# Get full country name to echo from country_of_manufacture attribute

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'd like to print out the country of origin for a product based on the country_of_manufacture attribute in Magento.  When I do the following:

```
<?php echo $_product->getCountryOfManufacture(); ?>
```

It will only print out the country code (ex: US or IT) rather than the full country name.  How can I get it so that it will display the full country name, the same way I choose it when editing a product?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('country_of_manufacture');?>
```